# PHP, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in

Tags: php, oop

I don't understand why this error occure.
I want change some string in array on data from database, so i used preg_replace_callback. But when I use in definition of callback function

```
$row = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
```

parser replies with error

All code:

```
    public function tRsql() {
        $argNums = func_num_args();
        $argsArr = func_get_args();

        function change($matches) {
            if(stripos($matches[0], "sql:")) {
                $str = ltrim($matches[0], "#sql:");
                $str = rtrim($str, ":");
                $row = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
                $str = $row[$str];
                return $str;
            } else {
                return $matches[0];
            }
        }
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->numOfRows; $i++) {
            $argsArr = preg_replace_callback("/(#sql\:)\S+\:/", "change", $argsArr);
            $this->tR(implode(",",$argsArr));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you learn to define a global function within a class method? This is not javascript. Make the `change` function a class method an you are fine.

Comment: The function `change` is _not_ a method of that object, but a dynamically created function in the global namespace. You certainly can define such a function for dynamic usage. But is is not more than that.

Comment: I tried this, but when I define 'change' func. as a class method other error occure: `preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'change', to be a valid callback in`

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this way:

```
public function tRsql() {
    $argNums = func_num_args();
    $argsArr = func_get_args();

    $change = function ($matches) {
        if(stripos($matches[0], "sql:")) {
            $str = ltrim($matches[0], "#sql:");
            $str = rtrim($str, ":");
            $row = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
            $str = $row[$str];
            return $str;
        } else {
            return $matches[0];
        }
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < $this->numOfRows; $i++) {
        $argsArr = preg_replace_callback("/(#sql\:)\S+\:/", $change, $argsArr);
        $this->tR(implode(",",$argsArr));
    }
}
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: I changed `"change"` on `"self::change"` and define function as method and errors disappered :D